# Compare Two Tables to Find Missing Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables - prod table shows employees and prod id that they are allowed to sell. 
Inv table has invoice numbers and the employee name and product.
Each employee eligible to see must be connected to that invoice. 
I want to compare these two tables to find which inv rows an eligible employee is missing.
The result I get from the compare query below is ok except that it does not include invoice 104 for prod 11 and employee b. 
The correct answer should be

```
101 c 11
102 d 12
104 b 11
104 c 11
```

Thanks in advance for help/

```
create table #prod
(
nameID int
, name nvarchar(255)
, prod nvarchar(255)
)

insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(1, 'a', 11)
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(2, 'b', 11 )
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(3, 'c', 11)
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(2, 'b', 12)
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(4, 'd', 12)
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(3, 'c', 13)
insert into #prod (nameID, name, prod)
values(4, 'd', 13)

create table #inv
(
inv_id int
, name nvarchar(255)
, prod nvarchar(255)
)

insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(101, 'a', 11)
insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(101, 'b', 11 )
insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(102, 'b', 12)
insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(102, 'c', 12)
insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(103, 'c', 13)
insert into #inv (inv_id, name, prod)
values(104, 'a', 11)
```

Comment: "the compare query below " does not seem to exist.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Compare query does not work so excluded it.
I can't use actual data, I have given all necessary info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  i.inv_id, p.name, p.prod
FROM #inv i
JOIN #prod p
  ON p.prod = i.prod
LEFT JOIN #inv v
  ON v.inv_id = i.inv_id AND
     v.name = p.name AND
     v.prod = p.prod
WHERE v.inv_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: damn, this is way more elegant than my answer, up voted this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct cs.*
from 
(
select inv.inv_id, prod.[name], prod.prod
from #inv inv , #prod prod
where
    inv.name <> prod.name and
    inv.prod = prod.prod
) cs
left join 
(
select inv.inv_id, inv.name, inv.prod
from #inv inv,#prod prod
where
    inv.name = prod.name and
    inv.prod = prod.prod
) b on cs.inv_id = b.inv_id and cs.name = b.name and cs.prod = b.prod
where
    b.inv_id is null
order by 
    1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somthing like this could help you if you have somthing like a foreign key in one table.

```
SELECT ID, Name
FROM   table1
WHERE  ID NOT IN (SELECT fID FROM table2)
```